# Codebase Organisation for Microservice using AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway, code-organization

Several different endpoints for a resource can exposed from `API Gateway` (e.g. - `/customer`), with different serverless functions deployed in `AWS Lambda` supporting `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE` operations on the resource. For each serverless function it has to be deployed separately in `AWS Lambda`. Now since they all work on a same `backend/data-model/underlying resource`, what should be the ideal structure for codebase for these serverless functions? Separate codebase for each endpoint, or one codebase with different handler to handle diff functions? What would be the Pro's and Cons for each?

Comment: I voted to close because this question is unlikely to have a single or a few "correct" answers. That being said, I've found that the tooling out there (e.g. serverless) makes it easier to work with a single code base which packages all of the handlers into one.

Comment: @Joel Cornett  Can you please elaborate on the packaging of multiple handlers into a singe one? Can we please get to know the alternatives before closing it out?